# Solving an absolute-value inequality: $−|x|+2 \geq 8x $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

How would I go about solving the domain of this inequality?
$$−|x|+2 \geq 8x $$
I can't combine the $x$'s so I don't know what to do.

Could I say:
$$-x + 2 ≥ 8x $$
and
$$x - 2 ≥ 8x $$
and solve the domain from there?

Comment: Yes... that is right.

Comment: Well, not "and" but "or".  You solve by assuming $x < 0$ and seeing what you get.  ANd then you assume $x \ge 0$ and you see what you get.  But be careful your conclusions must match your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

case 1: if $x\ge0$

$$-x+2\ge 8x$$
$$2\ge 9x$$
we get $$\frac{2}{9}\ge  x$$
but we already assumed $x\ge0$ thus
 $$\frac{2}{9}\ge  x\ge 0$$
case 2: if $x<0$
$$x+2\ge 8x$$
$$2\ge 7x$$

$$\frac{2}{7}\ge x$$

but we already assumed $x<0$ thus
we get $$x<0$$

Take the union of both solutions

Answer (score 2):

We can write $$2\geq 8x+|x|$$.
If we have $$x\geq 0$$ we have $$2\geq 8x+x$$
If $$x<0$$ then we get $$2\geq 8x-x$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

The case analysis gives

$$\begin{cases}x\ge0\to-x+2\ge8x,\\x\le0\to x+2\ge8x\end{cases}$$

or

$$\begin{cases}x\ge0\to x\le\frac29,\\x\le0\to x\le\frac27.\end{cases}$$

Combining the inequations, finally

$$x\le\frac29.$$